# Multithreading to process requests and save results in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, multithreading, csv

I was presented with a task to come up with a script that generates a CSV with POSTAL codes via bruteforce (I'm in Brazil, so that means CEP to us).

Points to note:

- I'm using an external library, but basically consuming a SOAP service provided by the Postal agency;
- I have a list of cities I have to get the results for, with variable ranges to be tested;
- I have 8 threads available for me, and using 7 to process and 1 to writing (Iw as scared of sincronism);

When formulating the solution, I had two paths:

1. Send a city to each thread, and wait for that city to finish processing.
2. Send the entire list of postal codes available for a city to all threads, and only grab the next city after it is all done.

Currently I opted for option 1, since I was thinking the number of requests and processing would be the same, but now it does seem a bit slow (it's been running for around 7 days and not done).

Problems:

- There're cities with huge ranges to test (like Sao Paulo, with 6.5M), which means a thread stuck processing it;
- but on the other hand, it's complicated to manage which cities have completed by going for option 2.

My input data is a CSV file, formatted like this (This is in Brazilian Portuguese):

```
Adamantina,17800-000 a 17809-999,Não codificada por logradouros,Total do município
Agudos,17120-001 a 17149-999,Codificado por logradouros,Total do município
```

My code is below. Some of the code can be ignored (like the logging statements):

```py
import threading
import csv
import queue
import time
from datetime import timedelta

import requests
import pycep_correios
from loguru import logger
from pycep_correios import HOMOLOGACAO, PRODUCAO
from tqdm import tqdm


def read_csv(csv_path: str):
    """Utility function to read CSV files

    Arguments:
        csv_path {str} -- path to the CSV file

    Returns:
        list -- a list of lists where each CSV row is a list
    """
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        return [list(row) for row in csv_reader]


def recover_range(range_string: str):
    """Utility function to recover the numeric range from string

    Given that the string is in a specific format, 
    we split it and get the numeric range

    Arguments:
        range_string {str} -- string containing the range, must be in format 'xxxxx-xxx a xxxxx-xxx'

    Returns:
        list -- list with the numeric range ([from, to])
    """
    cep_range = [v.replace('-', '') for v in range_string.split(' ')]
    cep_range = [int(v) for v in cep_range if v.isnumeric()]
    return cep_range


class DataWriterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        logger.info('Instantiating {} on {}', self.__class__.__name__,
                    self.name)
        self.queue = queue

    def write_to_file(self, content: dict):
        """Method to write content to the target CSV

        Arguments:
            content {dict} -- dictionary where each key is a column for the CSV
        """
        with open('output_sp.csv', 'a') as f:
            logger.info('{}: writing new register to CSV.', self.name)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, content.keys())
            writer.writerow(content)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            result = self.queue.get()
            self.write_to_file(result)
            self.queue.task_done()


class RequestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, in_queue: queue.Queue, out_queue: queue.Queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        logger.info('Instantiating {} on {}', self.__class__.__name__,
                    self.name)
        self.in_queue = in_queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            record = self.in_queue.get()
            for item in record:
                result = self.process(item)
                if result is not None:
                    self.out_queue.put(result)
            else:
                logger.success('{} has finished processing...', result['cidade'])
            self.in_queue.task_done()

    def process(self, record):
        """Processing method

        This method expects a CEP number as input, and will make a request 
        to the Correios API to check if it exists. In positive cases we 
        return the data, else None is returned.

        Arguments:
            record {int} -- CEP number

        Returns:
            dict -- Dictionary containing the valid CEP data, None if not found
        """
        cep = str(record)
        if len(cep) < 8:
            cep = '0{}'.format(cep)
        if pycep_correios.validar_cep(cep):
            try:
                address = pycep_correios.consultar_cep(cep=cep,
                                                        ambiente=HOMOLOGACAO)
                if address is not None:
                    logger.success('{}: {} is a valid CEP, saving...',
                                   self.name, cep)
                    return address
            except pycep_correios.excecoes.ExcecaoPyCEPCorreios as exc:
                logger.error('{}: Exception when processing: {} - [{}]',
                             self.name, cep, exc.message)
                return None
            except AttributeError as exc:
                logger.error('{}: CEP {} has AttributeError {}', self.name,
                             cep, exc)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                logger.warning(
                    '{}: Connection blocked, trying again in 60 seconds...',
                    self.name)
                time.sleep(60)  # After some time the SOAP service force disconnects
                # Recursive call to reprocess the item
                return self.process(cep)
        else:
            logger.error('{}: Invalid CEP {}', self.name, cep)
            return None


def main():
    lg = logger.add("events.log",
                    rotation="25 MB",
                    compression="zip",
                    format="{time} {level} {message}",
                    level="INFO")
    cep_list = read_csv('cep_sp.csv')  # read and preprocess ranges
    cep_list = [
        item for item in cep_list
        if item[1] and item[2] == 'Codificado por logradouros'
    ]
    cep_queue = queue.Queue()  # list of ceps to process
    result_queue = queue.Queue()  # results acquired

    for _ in range(3):  # 4 cores = 3 proc threads + 1 writer thread
        t = RequestThread(in_queue=cep_queue, out_queue=result_queue)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    # spawn threads to print
    t = DataWriterThread(result_queue)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    cep_processing_list = []
    for record in cep_list:
        cep_ranges = recover_range(record[1])
        if not cep_ranges:  # dealing with header rows
            continue
        else:
            cep_processing_list.append(
                [cep for cep in range(cep_ranges[0], cep_ranges[1])])

    # add paths to queue
    for record in tqdm(cep_processing_list):
        cep_queue.put(record)

    start_time = time.time()
    logger.info('Starting the script...')

    # wait for queue to get empty
    cep_queue.join()
    result_queue.join()

    logger.info('Finished. Done in {}.',
                str(timedelta(seconds=(time.time() - start_time))))
    logger.remove(lg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983938/python-appending-to-same-file-from-multiple-threads
```

The goals I want to achieve:

- Improve efficiency overall;
- Improve code to be cleaner and more compliant with Python guidelines (I tried my best);
- Get some advice if I should split this code in functions and files more;
- If possible, come up with a solution for the huge amount of data implied.

If more hardware is the only answer, there's nothing I can do. But I would like to do the best I can with the code. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: As this question has been around for some time and has not seem much activity besides the initial response I am marking it as solved, but if there're any pointers you would like to comment, you are free to do.

Comment: While unintuitive, you should know that the `threading` package does not actually do proper multithreading, it only simulates asynchronous threads. It's great for doing HTTP requests, and waiting for results. But you probably want to look at the `multiprocessing` package, which actually runs your code in parallel, and offers a speedup.

Comment: That's interesting to know. I am quite new to multithreading in python, thanks for the head up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Type hints for return values

You add `str` as a parameter hint, but you're missing a return value hint - for `read_csv` for instance, it should be `list`.

You're also missing a type hint for `queue`.

### Formatting leading zeros

Don't pre-convert `cep` to a string. Instead:

```
cep = '{:08d}'.format(cep)
```

### f-strings

```
logger.success(f'{self.name}: {cep} is a valid CEP, saving...')
```

### Recursion for retry

Don't! There's no need to recurse, and it's needlessly bloating your stack. Rather than recursing, use a simple loop.

### `continue` logic

```
    if not cep_ranges:  # dealing with header rows
        continue
    else:
        cep_processing_list.append(
            [cep for cep in range(cep_ranges[0], cep_ranges[1])])
```

should be

```
if cep_ranges:
    cep_processing_list.append(
        [cep for cep in range(cep_ranges[0], cep_ranges[1])])
```

Comment: Thank you for your pointers, I was not aware `loguru` supports f-strings directly. The recursion strategy is a hack, and your suggestion seems pretty much smarter.

Comment: An f-string, after formatting, turns into a regular string - so anything that accepts a `str` supports an f-string.

Comment: Overall, what do you think of the logic?